# How I can bound a checkBox with KeyPress event of a textBox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I'm new in C# visual programming and I'm facing a problem in winform that is I want to make the textBox accepts numbers only when a checkBox is checked ... the problem is that I know how to use the code inside KeyPress event but it doesn't work with the idea of checkBox.

I have this code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if(char.IsLetter(e.Keychar))
  {
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Now the question is how to make this happens when a checkBox is checked???

Comment: If you edit your question to show us what you've tried so far, we may be able to help...

Comment: Are you using winforms,wpf? Please show details about problem

Comment: Yes , I'm using winform applications

Answer (score 2):

on your key press event you could do:

```
if (this.checkBoxNumericOnly.Checked)
{
    //your code to only allow numerics...
}
```

Comment: I tried to write this code but after "this" keyward there is only checkbox1 is appearing there is nothing like "checkBoxNumericOnly" appear !!!

Comment: @Mouad - checkBoxNumericOnly is for example only. You would use whatever the name is of your checkbox (probably checkbox1)

Comment: now I want to write "," for once only and I have this code .... 
 if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == '.') || char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
                { e.Handled = false; }
                else
                { e.Handled = true; }
the problem is that the dot digit can be repeated for more than one time!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all of you ..

I wrote this code to enter numbers but only one dot '.' and it works finally ... thanks a lot for help

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)&&(e.KeyChar != '.') && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
            if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the  MaskedTextBox control and handle the checkbox event to change the [mask property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx)

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            maskedTextBox1.Mask = "000-000-0000";
        }
        else
        {
            maskedTextBox1.Mask = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you give me an example on that??

Comment: Thanks for help ... now I have two ways to write my code

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this in your `TextBox`'s keypress event :

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

            if(this.checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                //Allow only number
                if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }            
        }
```